# Updating clipPath transform not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

Here's a basic example to illustrate the problem, https://codesandbox.io/s/4rz9zmvj79. This doesn't work on Chrome 68/69, but it works fine on Firefox 62. It seems like Chrome doesn't support updating clipPath transform, but I'm not sure if this is a browser bug.

Comment: Why wouldn't it by a Chrome bug?

Comment: It also doesn't work on Safari, so just wanted to see if I was missing something

Comment: They both shared the same codebase at one time, presumably this bug has always been there.